# Stopping a user thread conditionally in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script running for x number of users. I want to conditionally close a user thread in a while controller. For example, if my while controller exits for a user thread, I need to stop the thread. Is it possible? Sorry if this is duplicate or a dumb question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are at least 2 options on how you can conditionally stop test thread or even the whole test:

1. Use [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler in combination with [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)
2. Use Beanshell Sampler or PostProcessor and invoke [setStopThread](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) method of SampleResult class. See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for example. For reference:

   ```
   if (condition){
       SampleResult.setStopThread(true); // for Beanshell Sampler
       prev.setStopThread(true); // for Beanshell Post Processor
   }
   ```

Comment: What are "SampleResult" and "prev" in this example? Are they variable that are setup beforehand or references to other element names in the test?

Answer (score 1):

ctx.getThread().stop() sets the "stop" flag in the current thread, it works anywhere the JMeterContext ctx is exposed.

I have just done and verified it in a complex test script.