# Jmeter how to stop only one thread, not all the threads.

Tags: csv, jmeter, config

I have 50 users in my ThreadGroup with 50 seconds rump up (50 rows in my .csv config file). After certain HTTP request I would like to test for certain condition,and if pass, continue to next HTTP requests. Soft of read on google that BeanShell Assertion with the code

```
String response = SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
if(response.contains("\"HasError\":true")){
        SampleResult.setStopThread(true);
}
```

should resolve my problem. But the problem is that this function actually stops the entire test execution, all remaining users (where I might have some more values at the .csv file to test). IS there any convenient way not to stop the entire test? If anybody faced that problem please advise.

Comment: try the answer here,http://stackoverflow.com/a/22742806/2575259. for BeanShell Assertion, you may you to try with prev.setStopThread(true); but not SampleResult.setStopThread

Comment: @Naveen There is no prev variable defined for BeanShell Assertion. Only available: Failure, FailureMessage, SampleResult, vars, props and log.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a thread to stop on Sampler error by configuring it in the [thread-group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) component. Mark the 'stop thread' in the 'Action to be taken after Sampler error' section.
To ensure that you get a Sampler error by configuring a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

Comment: Thanks for this information. I knew that it's possible through the ThreadGroup level. But my initial question was how to stop the thread programmatically, within the Bean Shell script.