# Finish/interrupt thread in JMeter (conditionally)

Tags: jmeter

I know [threads can be stopped by Test Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720973/stopping-a-user-thread-conditionally-in-jmeter), but then I cannot see them in `View Results Tree` if that action was done.

I want to see results of steps before thread was interrupted/finished, Can threads be finished successfully conditionally at specific point?

P.S. workaround would be to put next steps in other `if controller` with negation to finish condition, however I suspect it would require significant test plan changes.

ADD: version 2.13, in 5.1 there is `Break current loop` and it works as I need, but I have not moved my test plan to it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) had name replaced to `Flow Control Action`

You can choose [Stop](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) to complete samplers in progress

> The "Stop" action stops the thread or test after completing any samples that are in progress.

Also you have options to continue execution, but move to next iteration using

```
Go to next iteration of Current Loop
```

Or

```
Break Current Loop
```

Or

```
Start Next Thread Loop
```

[image]

Comment: how about `view results tree`?

Comment: it does not in my test runs. why could it be?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov can you add screenshot with test action and samplers not added? Are you expecting to stop only at the end of the thread?

Comment: ADD:if I choose next iteration then I see steps in results, if stop or stop now then does not. version 2.13 however in my other issues experiment with 5.1 gave same result.

Comment: Actually in 5.1 there is `break current loop` option which suits me, more reasons to switch...

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov There are lot of reasons https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html (also using latest jmeter plugins)